# Copy Column description from one dataset to another dataset approach |bigquery|cloudfunction gen2|

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to copy column level descriptions from `Dataset_t` to `Dataset_v` (*Dataset_v  contains views based on the Dataset_t tables*)  (Also assuming `tablename` is same as view name in both datasets).

Since this process needs to be automated, utilizing Cloud Function gen 2 (that provides native support for Eventarc triggers).

Below is what I have for now theoretically:

1. Added the Eventarc bigquery trigger `google.cloud.bigquery.v2.TableService.PatchTable` to get fired when an update to description is done to table in `Dataset_t`.

[image]

2. Route the logs from logging to GCS and from there determine inputs for python function that would update the views description.

Since I am in Kindergarten as far as GCP is concerned, please suggest what will be a good approach to achieve this?

Comment: Your question seems vague to me, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @JMGelilio I am trying to update the View column schema description from table level schema description. Basically when a viewA is created from TableA , view schema description is empty. So when i update the table Schema description with some data, it triggers functions that updates view schema description with the same data automatically.